# How to limit domain of Plot dynamically

Tags: plotting, regions

I have some function `f[x,a]` and I would like to plot it, on a subdomain of `{x,0,1}` that is dependent on `x` and `a` in some way, `g[x,f,a]<0`. At the moment I have, for example

```
Plot[Evaluate[Table[f[x,a], {a,3}]], {x,0,1}]
```

But `f` isn't well-defined beyond this subdomain so the output is nonsense and I would like it clipped. But the subdomain is different for each plot, etc. How can I add some clipping that enforces that domain constraint?

(This may not be easy in the general case, but it is sufficient here to assume that the constraint is satisfied at `x=0` and there will be some minimal nonzero `x` from which it will be violated and clipping from there is enough)

A minimal example can be really simple: `f[x_,a_]:=a x;` and `g[x_,f_,a_]:=f+a/10-1;`

Comment: please post a complete self contained example. Including definition of `f`. You can limit the plot range using the `PlotRange` option

Comment: @Nasser but it seems that `PlotRange` is constant, and I do not have an analytical expression for the limiting `x` since in reality `f` and `g` are solutions to equations, so they're interpolating functions, say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be kind of makeshift, but one possibility is to use the [`Piecewise`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html) function to limit the domain (setting the "default" value to `Undefined` or `Indeterminate`):

```
f[x_, a_] := a*x;
g[x_, f_, a_] := f[x, a] + a/10 - 1;

fplot[x_, a_] := Piecewise[
  {{f[x, a], g[x, f, a] < 0}},
  Undefined
  ]

Plot[
 Evaluate[Table[fplot[x, a], {a, 3}]], {x, -1, 1},
 PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}},
 PlotLegends -> (("a = " <> ToString@#) & /@ Range[3]),
 AspectRatio -> 1
 ]
```

[image: Example Plot]

Hopefully this is somewhat close to what you had in mind!

Comment: That's an excellent idea

Comment: Instead of `None`, the more conventional symbols used for this are either `Undefined` or `Indeterminate`.

Comment: Good to know, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `RegionFunction` to restrict the region that is displayed, although the pure function can only depend on the `x` and `y` coordinates. For your example, you could use:

```
g[x_, y_] := y + y/(10 x) - 1 < 0
```

Then:

```
Plot[
    Evaluate @ Table[f[x, a], {a, 3}], {x, -1, 1},
    RegionFunction -> g,
    PlotRange->{{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}
]
```

[image]